# EF core always create migration on IsRowVersion field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing asp.net core application with EF Core. I have Entity "Message". After I've add field

```
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

and configure it with IsRowVersion

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Message>(entity =>
        {
            ...
            entity.Property(c => c.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();
        });
```

I always have modifications in new migration:

```
 migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "Timestamp",
            table: "Messages",
            rowVersion: true,
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(DateTime),
            oldNullable: true);
```

I can create 10 new migrations an it will always contains this AlterColumn.

Why? How can i prevent of generating this AlterColumn instructions?

UPD: I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql connector